# Chrome shows two icons in Unity Launcher

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher, google-chrome

I am a new Ubuntu user. I just installed 12.04. To get Chrome on the Launcher, I clicked the BFB and searched for Chrome, then dragged that icon to the Launcher. However, when I run Chrome, it creates a second icon for the running chrome. Creating a second window creates a second triangle under the second Chrome icon, with the first icon not doing anything. It is also apparently not locked to the launcher and I can't remove it. Does anybody know how to remove the first icon? I have locked the second icon to the launcher and it seems to be working fine, but I don't want two icons.

Answer (score 11):

I periodically run into this problem and variants of it, most recently on Ubuntu 14.04.

Here's what has worked for me in these cases:

1. Close all Chrome windows (and choose **Exit** from the Chrome indicator menu, if you have one).
2. Right click on all Chrome icons in the launcher and choose **Unlock from Launcher**.
3. Open the **Files** application.

   1. Choose **Location** from the **Go** menu (or press **Ctrl-L**).
   2. Type `.local/share/applications` into the text field and press **Enter**.
   3. You should see a number of files whose names contain "chrome" (or "chromium" if you're using Chromium instead of Google Chrome. **Send these files to the Trash** (but leave any other files in this folder alone).
4. (You might have to log out and log back in at this point, but I don't think this is always necessary.)
5. Open the Dash and type `chrome`. You should see only 1 entry.
6. Launch Chrome and lock to the launcher (by right clicking on the icon and choosing **Lock to Launcher** or by dragging the icon out to the right of the launcher and then back in at a different location).
7. Close the Chrome window, and then use the launcher icon to reopen it. It should open normally and you should not see a 2nd icon appear.

Comment: Excellent answer. Can confirm, that this does still work as of Ubuntu 15.10 btw

Comment: And this still works for ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that when you have a lot of "chrome" apps then removing all the chrome-* files might be a lot of trouble.

Try listing all the apps using the following

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications
grep Name chrome*
```

There might be a line with something that is clearly not an app, in my case something with "Name=Chrome New Tab", remove that one and maybe clear  out a few apps you are no longer using.

Restart Chrome, lock the item and quit/restart to see if issue is fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/842257).

Try the following:

`unity --reset-icons`

The above command will reset the icons the way they were when you first installed Ubuntu.

or type:

`gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop`

and remove the following line:

`OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Good idea, but.. didn't work. Found this while Googling...